# Disable over-helpful security daemon

Tags: settings

I really do love all things Linux and Ubuntu is awesome,

It's just one little niggle I've ran into since using Ubuntu,
and that is the admin/privilege service that comes along with Ubuntu, i fully understand the concepts and usage of root/admin users but still seem to find myself in sparse moments of frustration when transferring files to and from root.

More specifically a `Permission Denied` by the system when attempting to move a file from the `/root/` folder to the desktop of my user regardless of using `sudo`.

i'm not fully certain yet which daemons are responsible for which jobs but i'm assuming that is the cause of restrictions between root and general users.

*I would be most grateful if anybody knows a tweak or touch to help make it a touch more comfortable?*

Comment: Comfortable in what sense ? Please be more specific as to what you would want to be tweaked.

Comment: when using a certain wireless packet capture program it saves the output to root directory by default, it seems only since i last logged on that i'm being denied permission when trying to transfer the file to the desktop regardless of using sudo, sudo su or sudo -i. i have managed to move it to the desktop but i was a bit heavy handed in doing so, i just can't see the reason why ubuntu is suddenly behaving differently, i was hoping somebody had an answer to relaxing the security in any way as to means of making it easier to flow about buisiness...cheers

Comment: Congrats!  You're not new any more!  Rep 8 user already!  **;-)**

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you do not **fully** understand the concepts and usage of root/admin users: there is no daemon that does what you're describing: it's just built into the file system.

`root` has access to everything, an admin has access to admin things and a user has access to user things.

To allow a user to have access to a file owned by root, execute the following command (as root):

```
chown szUserName:szUserGroup szFileName
```

and your user will be able to read the root file.

Comment: Thank you for your'e help, just when i think I've gotten the size of it another easier way around turns up : ) love it

Comment: **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**  We've all been there!  Read the manual page for `chown` and you'll know much more. @Mr.Sam